# How to add participant description in mermaid.js?

Tags: markdown, sequence-diagram, mermaid

I need to add a description for every participant in the mermaid.js sequence diagram.

Adding notes is not the right approach here since they are not placed parallel to one another as the participants, they are placed as shown below.

```
[participant-1]    [participant-2]    [participant-3]
[note-1]               |                   |
                   [note-2]                |
                                      [note-3]
```

I could not find any such feature in the [doc](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/sequenceDiagram.html).

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [participant Alias](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/sequenceDiagram.html#aliases) to achieve this? It works reasonably well for me in Azure DevOps Wiki, which has limited Mermaid support. Your mileage may vary.

Azure DevOps Wiki's Mermaid doesn't like the dash '`-`' character in your participant names so I removed it in the example below. The following seems to work for me. Know too you can use `<br/>` for line breaks, giving your participant a multi-lined "note." Although, in Azure DevOps Wiki, if you have too much text it gets 'wonky.'

```
sequenceDiagram
    participant participant1 as note-1
    participant participant2 as note-2
    participant participant3 as note-3
```

For me, this yields something like:

```
[note-1]   [note-2]   [note-3]
```

Comment: Or, you might want something like `participant participant1 as participant-1<br/>note-1`, yielding a multi-line participant name that includes the lines `participant-1` and `note-1` in the participant description (inside the 'box').

Comment: Sure, we can add text within the participant component, I was wondering if there is any official way to add a description as there is for notes. I think for now I will have to use your solution.